# How to know when a drive failed in RAID1

Tags: hard-drive, raid

I want to make sure my backup are safe. I use one main SSD running Ubuntu and I have 2X 2Tb HDD in RAID1 for my data. How to know when a disk fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could definitely check the disk SMART data.

If you use ubuntu desktop, run the `Disk utility` in ubuntu:
[image: Disk utility - SMART data]

If you use a server, you can install smartmontools:

```
sudo apt-get install smartmontools
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdx
```

where you substitute "/dev/sdx" with your drive.

Comment: It say that SMART status is not supported?

Comment: On the SSD or on the 2Tb HDDs ? Try the second solution, using smartmontools

Comment: The SSD is supporterd but not the 2Tb HDDs. I will try smartmontools solution.

Comment: /media/52306816306802F9: Unable to detect device type
Smartctl: please specify device type with the -d option.

Comment: It is working with the SSD /dev/sda

Comment: (1) Which ubuntu version are you using? 11.10? (2) Are you using hardware or software raid? (3) Are the disks connected on sata? (4) Try using the -d as suggested by smartctl, here is the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/smartctl.8.html#contenttoc5) (See "options")

Comment: 1- Ubuntu desktop 11.10 ; 2-Onboard Marvell RAID controller ; 3- Sata II.  Thank's for the manpage. I tried specifying the right swith -d Marvell but then I get: Smartctl: Device Read Identity Failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options. So I am getting a bit confused.

Comment: If I use more permissive tolerance switch it doens't work either.

Comment: Maybe when the computer boot up the Marvell controller BIOS will give an error message if a disk fail?

Comment: Try using `mount`, use /dev/xxx instead of /media/xxx. Otherwise I don't know what else to suggest, maybe compile the new smartmontools 5.42? If the drives are brand new, I don't think you need to worry for now -- my 80gb is alive for 3.6 years according to the SMART data. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a GUI, you can ask `mdadm` about the status of the RAID array

```
sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
```

That will list the Active, Working, Failed, and Spare devices for the array